Spam flags cast automatic downvotes on Staging Ground questions
There is no votes shown in SG posts so I used to think that SG posts didn't have scores. But I after raised a red flag on an SG post:

So... SG posts can actually be (down-)voted? Will this affect the rep of OP?

Spam and R/A flags raise an automated system downvote. This was also reported during the beta, marked as [status-deferred] with a ticket created for it but i think it isn't much of an issue.

"Will this affect the rep of OP?" -- if they're spamming, might as well. I don't really see any harm in that, more of the opposite.

I know voting is disabled for Staging Grounds, but this is a cool gauge for how many other people have pending spam flags on the post. And also, the idea that their spam is being downvoted despite being under the 'protection' of Staging Ground, is satisfying. In other words, I hope this 'bug' does not get fixed.
